need to customize my keyboard layout to use the key (>/<) which is at an unusual place on my keyboard
I've got a Dell laptop Dell Inc. XPS 13 9360 and my keyboard has this key at the place usually dedicated for right CTRL (see this pic, not mine but same place)
_____
| >  |
| <  |
_____

("greater than" and "lesser than")
which has no effect when I press it (actually it does, it behaves like CTRL.)
I'd like to create a custom mapping to make it work, but I can't succeed...
I've tried sudo evtest /dev/input/event4 (where event4 correspond to the keyboard), here's what it gives me when I press - one time only - this key:
Event: time 1717065169.229204, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1717065169.229204, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1717065169.271196, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9d
Event: time 1717065169.271196, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 97 (KEY_RIGHTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1717065169.271196, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

In addition sudo showkey --scancodes gives:
0xe0 0x1d 0xe0 0x9d

and sudo showkey --keycodes:
code clavier  97 appuyé
code clavier  97 relâché

I'm using archlinux
additionnal info :
$ localectl
System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: fr
   X11 Layout: fr
$ setxkbmap -query
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an Xwayland server
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us


How can I make it work ... (For both > and < (without/with SHIFT key)
...tried setkeycodes but not sure how to use it) ?
...Is a keymap the solution ?)

It’s a perfectly normal key for AZERTY keyboards, but you might need to use a compatible layout (AZERTY, BÉPO etc.).

@StephenKitt ok this is AZERTY indeed, and all other keys are operationnal. How can I achieve to identify (and set) a better layout than - apparently - the one i've set at install... ? (the key is near AltGr, like on this pic)

Huh, that’s not the key I was expecting — the one I’m thinking of is next to the left Shift key. Your key is in a position usually occupied by Ctrl, or one of the Windows keys; that might explain why it produces a Ctrl code… I’m afraid I don’t know how to address that (otherwise I’d answer rather than comment).

I've found a utility (with GUI) called input-remapper that accepts keycodes to re-map keys, but I don't know which keycode.s I can use, or where to find it.them. Playing with the keys, I've found out that AltGr+Shift+Z is <, and AltGr+Shift+X is >, I'll go with that for the moment
